# Laravel FFMpeg upload video and concat with request

Tags: php, laravel

i have problem when i upload video from (form HTML) 
i use Laravel FFMpeg package 
this code from my controller

```
$file = $request->file('video'); // take video request
FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')
    ->open(['vid\vid_one.mp4' , $file]) // concat video here and i think there is a problem
    ->export()
    ->concatWithoutTranscoding()
    ->save('contacct.mp4');
```

Comment: I think you need to add `$file->getRealPath()` to the array, since the `$file` will most likely be an [`UploadedFile`](http://l3.shihan.me/api/class-Symfony.Component.HttpFoundation.File.UploadedFile.html) object

Comment: it's appear to my this error (Unable to save concatenated video)

Comment: What's the problem with the given code? Are you facing any problem? Then please edit your question to contain all details

Answer (score 0):

You have to store that video on that point where you are using ffmpeg open function with this function:

```
$request->file('video')->storeAs('folderName', $request->video->getClientOriginalName(), 'diskName');
```